# Angular 9 Ivy error <mat-form-field> with multiple mat-hints

Tags: angular, ivy

Before update to angular9 Ivy I used to have multiple mat-hints in single

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field hintLabel="Max 10 characters" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter some input</mat-label>
    <input matInput #input maxlength="10" placeholder="Ex. Nougat">
    <mat-hint align="end">{{input.value?.length || 0}}/10</mat-hint>

    <mat-label>Select me</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-hint align="end">Here's the dropdown arrow ^</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

But now, i am getting error ERROR
Error: A hint was already declared for 'align="end"'.

I see in angular file form-field.js that arrow function used:

```
 (hint) => {
                if (hint.align === 'start') {
                    if (startHint || this.hintLabel) {
                        throw getMatFormFieldDuplicatedHintError('start');
                    }
                    startHint = hint;
                }
                else if (hint.align === 'end') {
                    if (endHint) {
                        throw getMatFormFieldDuplicatedHintError('end');
                    }
                    endHint = hint;
                }
```

before

```
  function (hint) {
                if (hint.align === 'start') {
                    if (startHint_1 || _this.hintLabel) {
                        throw getMatFormFieldDuplicatedHintError('start');
                    }
                    startHint_1 = hint;
                }
                else if (hint.align === 'end') {
                    if (endHint_1) {
                        throw getMatFormFieldDuplicatedHintError('end');
                    }
                    endHint_1 = hint;
                }
```

Maybe that the reason for that error?

Answer (score 0):

A mat-form-field can have maximum of 2 mat-hint s. If we are not specifying align, default is align="start". If we have 2 mat-hints, one should be align="start" and another should be align="end". In your case, you used both as align="end". If you change any one to align="start", it will fix the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!